# Spring Boot: NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException between test and main

Tags: spring, testing, spring-boot, component-scan

I have a SpringBoot main/Application.java class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value = "com.nfl.dm.shield", excludeFilters =
        {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(value = MemoryRepository.class, type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE)
        }
)
public class Application {

    final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.info("Booting application...");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

and a similar one for Test

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.nfl.dm.shield"}, excludeFilters =
        {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(value = MySqlRepository.class, type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE)
        }
)
public class ApplicationTestConfig {
}
```

The main code runs correctly.  The test code throws NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException, appearing to not properly filter out the unwanted MySqlRepository component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After over a day of trying many different ways to exclude the unwanted bean, the core issue turned out to be the fact that @ComponentScan was pulling in both Application and ApplicationTest, resulting in an additional scan for Application, resulting in the unwanted service being loaded.

The solution, add:

```
                @ComponentScan.Filter(value = Application.class, type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE)
```

to the list in ApplicationTestConfig.java.  So, when ApplicationTestConfig is loaded and triggers the component scan, it ignores Application (and all of Application's specific configurations).

Comment: This Q&A helped to understand my configuration and consequently solve my issue.
I created beans in *main* and *test* packages. Because in Junit tests I was using specific @ContextConfiguration I didn't have problems. Then I started to write integration tests that had to used default context, but it also picked up beand from test package. With the excludeFilters I managed to get a clean dependency tree.